# What happens if you interrupt a Git push?

Tags: git

I ran the following command:

```
git push -u origin master
```

The "push" was very big, many files, so it was taking time to upload. Halfway through I noticed I forgot to add a couple of files. So I did `"Ctrl + C"` in terminal (interrupting Git), and then after doing `git add .` , I committed again, and then pushed again.

Will Git know that the first one didn't go through ? It takes a really long time to push (so I can't test it easily. I have to wait for the push to finish which could take a while).

EDIT: Hooray! Nothing seems to have gone terribly wrong. All I did was push again, and everything works. :{

Comment: I would doubt anything major would happen, but if it did, it shouldn't be an issue - you've got a copy of the repository on your box, so if push were to come to shove, you could promote *that* to remote again.  I think the bigger problem is that you're storing binary blobs in Git and it's really not meant for that...

Comment: why don't you try it....

Comment: binary blobs ? I don't know what you mean. Its source code (node.js). I was trying it, but it takes a really long time on my asymmetric dsl, and as I have a presentation in a few hours, was just trying to save time...... XD

Comment: You didn't push it real good

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The upstream Git repository will be oblivious to your attempted push, and no change will occur upstream. Unfortunately however, as it doesn't do anything with the half-pushed files, it doesn't store it and then expect a continuation of the push later on either. So it's either push or don't push, there is no try;)

Answer (score 0):

If this happened try pushing one more time by adding the branch name to it
`git push origin Branch Name`