# git ensure that commit is fully pushed

Tags: git, github, push, commit

I was working on a project today and and pushed a commit inside my terminal window of phpstorm. I then closed phpstorm but then suddenly a feeling came over me: Did I fully wait until the push process was done?

I went to GitHub and checked the last commit and it seems that everything is there. I cloned the respository (I only have a master branch) and it has the latest files seemingly.

Can I somehow check if the commit is really pushed? In GitHub or via git command line?
Is it possible that only half or 4/5 of the commit is pushed and not the rest?

I searched Google for if git stores its terminal output in a logfile but apparently this is not the case.

I'm really afraid that I aborted the push accidently. Everything seems right, but I am really paranoid right now.

Comment: You can also check this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27326178/what-happens-if-you-interrupt-a-git-push/27326262

Answer (score 1):

You can run `git fsck` in your new clone to confirm that all is there.

---

The very fact that the checkout of the last commit worked without error in your fresh clone is already a proof that all files mentioned in the commit are also stored in the repo.

Comment: _"The very fact that the checkout of the last commit worked without an error is already a proof that all files mentioned in the commit are also stored in the repo."_ - please provide proof. In comparison, the fact that a directory (or even contains all desired filenames) is there does not mean that all files were fully copied from source to destination.

Comment: on a fresh clone it is without ambiguity (updated that point)